# SAS dropping more than 400 columns during proc transpose?? (I do not want it to drop these columns)

Tags: sas

I have some code that reads in some data and then transposes it. However, when I tranpose the data, the resulting dataset is missing over 400 columns that were in the input dataset. I have never seen this happen before and can't find any information online as to why this would happen. Any help is much, much appreciated!

The input dataset (mydata) has 716 unique entries in the column "MyCol1". This is the column that becomes the column header in the transposed dataset. The ttransposed dataset has only 269 columns!

```
libname in "\\folder1\folder2"; 
data mydata;
set in.mydata; run;

PROC SORT DATA=mydata nodupkey; 
BY MyCol3 MyCol4;
RUN;

PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=mydata OUT=mydata_WIDE(DROP=_NAME_);
BY MyCol3 MyCol4;
ID  MyCol1;
VAR MyCol2;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK update for anybody else who may have this error: during my proc sort statement I was accidentally deleting a bunch of rows.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should include MYCOL1 in the BY statement of the PROC SORT.  Otherwise only one of the MYCOL1 values will exist per group.

But you probably need to keep the NODUPKEY as duplicate values of MYCOL1 per group will cause trouble for the PROC TRANSPOSE as you cannot make two new variables with the same name.

```
PROC SORT DATA=mydata nodupkey; 
  BY MyCol3 MyCol4 MyCol1;
RUN;

PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=mydata OUT=mydata_WIDE(DROP=_NAME_);
  BY MyCol3 MyCol4;
  ID  MyCol1;
  VAR MyCol2;
RUN;
```